# Update part of existing ui component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

here is the component I have and want to modify (I just need to add a simple sentence in there, nothing that "should be" too hard) :

```
    <field name="imageUploader_0">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image 3</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="plp/plp/imageupload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Which gives this result

[image: image component]

My goal is to add some text under Maximum file size.

I manage to found that Maximul file size was located in `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/uploader/image.html`

But I can't see where is the link with that html page and the template that seems to be used : `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/template/image-preview.html`

Also, I don't want to add that text each time this image-preview is called but only on that specific case...so I guess I probably have to make my own extends from the template to make it different from the catalog one...but as I don't see the link between `image-preview.html` and `image.html` I'm kinda lost in there. I'm also really newbie with ui component.

Thanks for your assistance.

This is the image-preview.html from magento

```
<div class="file-uploader-summary">
    <div class="file-uploader-preview image-uploader-preview">
        <a class="image-uploader-preview-link" attr="href: $parent.getFilePreview($file)" target="_blank">
            <div class="file-uploader-spinner image-uploader-spinner" />
            <img
                class="preview-image"
                tabindex="0"
                event="load: $parent.onPreviewLoad.bind($parent)"
                attr="
                    src: $parent.getFilePreview($file),
                    alt: $file.name,
                    title: $file.name">
        </a>

        <div class="actions">
            <button
                type="button"
                class="action-remove"
                data-role="delete-button"
                attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
                disable="$parent.disabled"
                click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
                <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
    <div class="file-uploader-meta">
        <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text args="$file.previewHeight"/>,
        <text args="$parent.formatSize($file.size)"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this this is the `image.html`

```
<div class="admin__field" visible="visible" css="$data.additionalClasses">
    <label class="admin__field-label" if="$data.label" attr="for: uid">
        <span translate="label" attr="'data-config-scope': $data.scopeLabel"/>
    </label>

    <div class="admin__field-control" css="'_with-tooltip': $data.tooltip">
        <div class="file-uploader image-uploader" data-role="drop-zone" css="_loading: isLoading">
            <div class="file-uploader-area">
                <input type="file" afterRender="onElementRender" attr="id: uid, name: inputName, multiple: isMultipleFiles" disable="disabled" />
                <label class="file-uploader-button action-default" attr="for: uid, disabled: disabled" disable="disabled" translate="'Upload'" />
                <label
                    data-bind="event: {change: addFileFromMediaGallery, click: openMediaBrowserDialog}"
                    class="file-uploader-button action-default"
                    attr="id: mediaGalleryUid, disabled: disabled"
                    data-force_static_path="1"
                    translate="'Select from Gallery'"/>
                <render args="fallbackResetTpl" if="$data.showFallbackReset && $data.isDifferedFromDefault"/>
                <p class="image-upload-requirements">
                    <span if="$data.maxFileSize">
                        <span translate="'Maximum file size'" />: <text args="formatSize($data.maxFileSize)"/>.
                    </span>
                    <span if="$data.allowedExtensions">
                        <span translate="'Allowed file types'" />: <text args="getAllowedFileExtensionsInCommaDelimitedFormat()"/>.
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>

            <render args="tooltipTpl" if="$data.tooltip"/>

            <div class="admin__field-note" if="$data.notice" attr="id: noticeId">
                <span html="notice"/>
            </div>

            <label class="admin__field-error" if="error" attr="for: uid" text="error"/>

            <each args="data: value, as: '$file'" render="$parent.getPreviewTmpl($file)"/>

            <div if="!hasData()" class="image image-placeholder" click="triggerImageUpload">
                <div class="file-uploader-summary product-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="file-uploader-spinner image-uploader-spinner" />
                    <p class="image-placeholder-text" translate="'Browse to find or drag image here'"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <render args="$data.service.template" if="$data.hasService()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to test it on my local, but....did you see that part on image.html?

That directive render other html files. So, I am pretty sure that is you are looking for.

Good luck!